# Flip-flop with numbered inputs

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, ttl, diagram, sequential-logic

On page 3 of the [datasheet for the SN74LS597 IC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls597.pdf), I have found the following diagram:

[image: SN74LS597 logic diagram]

Notice that the flip-flops have some numbered inputs (1D and C1, 2D and C2, C3 and 3S/3R) and some simple inputs (S and R). What are these numbers for? Are they indications of synchronicity? Why different numbers?

Comment: they used numbers (C1, 1D, C2, 2D, C3, 3S, 3R) to distinguish the inputs/outputs of the three different types of FFs in the circuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers are just to indicate different types of behavior of the inputs.

The 3S/3R inputs are synchronous so that the output rank of registers can act as a shift register when clocked by SRCK.

S and R are asynchronous so that the shift register can be parallel loaded from the first rank of registers when SRLOAD is asserted. (or cleared when SRCLR is asserted).

RCK is used to synchronously load data into the first rank of registers for subsequent transfer into the shift register.

It seems peculiar that they would go into the detail of the 3S/3R rather than just calling them a D input.

Comment: Better answer than mine, thanks. I was wondering why they bothered drawing out 3S and 3R separately too.

Answer (score 2):

They appear to be used to differentiate between three different designs of flip-flop used in the chip. Notice how all the instances of 1 are on the same type of flip-flop, with the same inputs and outputs, but then all the 2s are on a flip-flop that has not only a D input but also S and R inputs. Then all the 3s are on a third type, which have dual S and R inputs each.

Comment: Makes sense. Are the S and R inputs asynchronous?

Comment: No clue. I would imagine one of the sets S/R and 3S/3R is probably asynchronous, but I couldn't tell you for sure.

Comment: By looking at the timing diagram in page 8, it seems that's the case.

Comment: Yes it’s synchronous and these in CMOS are now called PISO registers. Parallel in Serial Out